# Error with Facebook API Fatal error: (Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating application)

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

i'm a beginner with the Facebook API. i just created an application and i want to display name and number of friends:

this is my code:

```
<?php

require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$appapikey = '133XXXX60164049';
$appsecret = '  ce6a47dfd838WWWWWW34f387b28633660';

$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

echo "<p>Hello <fb:name uid=\"$user_id\" useyou=\"false\" linked=\"false\" firstnameonly=\"true\"></fb:name>, you have ".count($friends)." friends";

foreach($friends as $friend){
     $infos.=$friend.",";
}

$infos = substr($infos,0,strlen($infos)-1);

$gender=$facebook->api_client->users_getInfo($infos,'sex');

$gender_array = array(); 

foreach($gender as $gendervalue){
     $gender_array[$gendervalue[sex]]++;
}

$male = round($gender_array[male]*100/($gender_array[male]+$gender_array[female]),2);
$female = 100-$male;

echo "<ul><li>Males: $male%</li><li>Females: $female%</li></ul>";

?>
```

i got this

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating application. Cannot get application info due to a system error. thrown in D:\softs\UwAmp\www\facebook-php-sdk\src\base_facebook.php on line 1238

---

I tried to display only the username like this :

```
<?php

require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$appapikey = '453976ergerger647366';
$appsecret = 'fexxxxxxxxeb39bbce717b8062';

$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();



echo "<p>Hello <fb:name uid=\"$user_id\" useyou=\"false\" linked=\"false\" firstnameonly=\"true\"></fb:name>";
 ?>
```

But it's not working. Only "Hello" appears :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in the `foreach($friends as $friend)` section.

If I am correct, it returns you {data} with an array. so you would need to say

```
foreach(friends['data'] as $friend)
```

maybe do some commenting, to see where the error is and make a `print_r($friends)` to see how the array looks like!

Comment: With some comments, i can say the error occurs on this line :

$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

Comment: i tried to add this instead : 
$friends = $facebook->api_client->friends_get(); but still the same problem

Comment: remove it and check if you can display the $user_id

Comment: that doesn't answer my question: can you display `$user_id`?

Comment: then I'm sorry - but you have implemented the SDK the wrong way. Check [the official Facebook SDK Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) and make sure you have the latest version.